# Anchors (<a href="URL">URL</a>) instead of text (<p>URL</p>)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to achieve the following logic:

If URL in text is surrounded by paragraph tags (Example: `<p>URL</p>`), replace it in place to become a link instead: `<a href="URL">Click Here</a>`

The original file is a database dump (sql, UTF-8). Some URLs already exist in the desired format. I need to fix the missing links.

I am working on a script, which uses Beautifulsoup. If other solutions are make more sense (regex, etc.), I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you've already done, note any issues you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for all `p` elements that has a text starting with `http`. Then, [replace it with](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) a link:

```
for elm in soup.find_all("p", text=lambda text: text and text.startswith("http")):
    elm.replace_with(soup.new_tag("a", href=elm.get_text()))
```

Example working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <p>http://google.com</p>
    <p>https://stackoverflow.com</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for elm in soup.find_all("p", text=lambda text: text and text.startswith("http")):
    elm.replace_with(soup.new_tag("a", href=elm.get_text()))

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div>
  <a href="http://google.com"></a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
</div>
```

I can imagine this approach break, but it should be a good start for you.

---

If you additionally want to add texts to your links, set the `.string` property:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for elm in soup.find_all("p", text=lambda text: text and text.startswith("http")):
    a = soup.new_tag("a", href=elm.get_text())
    a.string = "link"
    elm.replace_with(a)
```

Comment: Alexander, thank you for your prompt response. I have tested your solution. It works fairly well. One more quick question if you don't mind. How do I decorate the anchors with a static text, so they do not appear empty? For instance, a href="http://google.com>Click Here</a> instead of just empty tags?